# Can my optimization take a small vector for one of its arguments in R?

Tags: r, function, optimization, vectorization

I have a small optimization below. I was wondering if it might be possible that for argument "`alpha`" in both my `f` function and in my `optimize()`, they could accept the vector `c(.025, .975)` instead of just taking only a single value (now, `alpha = .025`)?

```
N = 10 ; df = N-1 ; d = 1.356617

f <- function (ncp, alpha, q, df) {
       abs(suppressWarnings(pt(q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - alpha)
  }

optimize(f, interval = c(-20, 20), alpha = .025, q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, tol = 1e-10)[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrapping `optimize` in `sapply` does the trick with this example

```
sapply(c(0.025, 0.975),
       function(x) optimize(f, interval = c(-20, 20), alpha = x,
                            q = d*sqrt(N), df = df, tol = 1e-10)[[1]])
[1] 1.467169 6.997613
```

Here, you just loop through each desired value of alpha and apply `optimize` with it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly and if `sqrt(N)` is a scalar (numeric vector of length 1) as it is in the example above. Then just divide the whole thing by `sqrt(N)`, like `sapply(...) / sqrt(N)`.